# Add SKNode as trigger so that it does not affect other node's path

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I was wondering if it is possible to add an SKSpriteNode and give it a physics body/properties such that it functions only as a trigger. It can be thought of as a finish line in a race. When you pass the line, you get a point or something, but your path does not get physically/visually affected; you pass right through it. I am sure that this is possible, however, I do not know how to achieve this. Here is what I currently have for my sprite:

```
var revolutionBar = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
revolutionBar.alpha = 1
revolutionBar.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
revolutionBar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
revolutionBar.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.addChild(revolutionBar)
```

What should I add so that what I want is achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you are trying to achieve is to fire off a function after passing the line, you would do this by first setting that `SKSpriteNode` to have a `categoryBitMask` and a `collisionBitMask`.

Next you write a `didBeginContact` function in your swift file and you handle the conditions that checks that those are the right nodes for you to trigger this event.